# How to 'backspace' using a pushbutton

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QLabel that updates with digits as push buttons are clicked. Is there a way to delete, or 'backspace' using a push button?

Each push button appends a number (0-9) to the QLabel when clicked using this code:

```cpp
ui->Label->setText(ui->Label->text() + "1");
```

is there an easy way to use similar code to delete a digit?

Comment: Have you looked at any kind of [`QString` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)? Have you tried using any of the functions in there, such as `chopped`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `chopped(int len)`[1] as stated you in @Angew's comment:

```cpp
ui->Label->setText(ui->Label->text().chopped(1));
```

[1] https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#chopped